# output a variable by referencing another variable that has the same value as the name of the first variable

Tags: python

I have a variable and i want to use it to reference another varable that has the same name as the value of the first variable.the first vars value is str

```
var1 = "SUCCES"

def main():
    var2 = "var1"
    print(var2)
```

I want var 1 to be the output of this,is there any way?

Comment: You can declare `var1` as global variable using `global var1`

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have pointers so you can't do this, if you want to get the value of a variable by its name you can use `globals`:

```py
var1 = "SUCCES"

def main():
    var2 = globals()["var1"]
    print(var2)
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding for a long time,thank you for your answear.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing "var1" as a string to var2 not as a variable. You should only write var2 = var1. Also, you are just defining the main function and not calling it anywhere. The correct code would be:

```
var1 = "SUCCES"

def main():
    var2 = var1
    print(var2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding in a long time,but thank you for your answar.